# Generate a random u8 from 0 to 255 inclusively

Tags: random, rust

I am trying to make a program that generates random numbers from 0 to 255 inclusively. It seems so simple! I did this:

```
extern crate rand;
use rand::Rng;

fn main() {
    println!("Guess the number!");
    let random_number: u8 = rand::thread_rng().gen_range(0, 255);

    println!("Your random number is {}", random_number);
}
```

This works fine, but the problem with this approach is that [the number 255 will not be included](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/second-edition/ch02-00-guessing-game-tutorial.html#generating-a-random-number):

> The `gen_range` method takes two numbers as arguments and generates a random number between them. It’s inclusive on the lower bound but exclusive on the upper bound.

When I try to do this :

```
let random_number: u8 = rand::thread_rng().gen_range(0, 256);
```

Rust will generate a warning because `u8` only accepts values from 0 to 255.

```
warning: literal out of range for u8
 --> src/main.rs:6:61
  |
6 |     let random_number: u8 = rand::thread_rng().gen_range(0, 256);
  |                                                             ^^^
  |
  = note: #[warn(overflowing_literals)] on by default
```

How do I work around this without having to change the type of the `random_number` variable?

Comment: The API of gen_range function isn't useful. If we want to generate a u8 value from 240 to 255(inclusive), we must transform the type to what is bigger than u8.

Comment: @user3032481 As a bit of a hack, you could write `gen_range(239, 255) + 1`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the [`gen`](https://docs.rs/rand/0.3.18/rand/trait.Rng.html#method.gen) method instead. This method will generate a random value from the whole set of possible values for the specified type.

```
extern crate rand;

use rand::Rng;

fn main() {
    println!("Guess the number!");
    let random_number: u8 = rand::thread_rng().gen();

    println!("Your random number is {}", random_number);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled on this same issue and wondered why I could not use `.gen_range(0, 256);` for a `u8`.

The `.gen_range()` function signature looks like this ([docs](https://rust-random.github.io/rand/rand/trait.Rng.html#method.gen_range))

```rust
fn gen_range<T: SampleUniform, B1, B2>(&mut self, low: B1, high: B2) -> T where
    B1: SampleBorrow<T> + Sized,
    B2: SampleBorrow<T> + Sized,
```

The arguments we are trying to use are `0` and `256` which enter the function as integers and the default integer type is `i32`. However, this line

```rust
let random_number: u8 = rand::thread_rng().gen_range(0, 256);
```

reassigns the result of `.gen_range()` to a `u8`, the compiler tries to resolve `B1` and `B2` both as `u8`, making the generics in the function call evaluate like this

```rust
gen_range<u8>(B1, B2) -> u8 where 
    B1: SampleBorrow<u8> + Sized,
    B2: SampleBorrow<u8> + Sized,
```

256 will not fit into a `u8` causing the compiler to throw the `overflowing_literals` warning.

The correct way to calculate a random number with a maximum range of a primitive is pointed out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47724046/7435844), by letting the explicit type declaration define the generic constraints.

Ex:

```rust
use rand::Rng;
let random_with_range: u8 = rand::thread_rng().gen();
```